# Multitenancy, help understand concept of WorkContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, multi-tenant

While trying to understand how a multitenant environment works, I've came up to the concept of WorkContext.

#### Introduction:

In a **multitenant** environment Tenants are Clients which share similar functionality, and run under a single instance of a ROOT application. In order to be able to add tenant specific functionality I came across a conclusion that **Dependency Injection** is the right solution for my case.

Each tenant should have it's own **IoC Container**, in order to be able to Resolve its dependencies at runtime.

But when trying to implement the theory I have some troubles with the **wrapping out all tenant specific data**.

While digging the internet it seems that there must exist some sort of a TenantContext. So each tenant has it's own isolated Context.

**The problem is that I don't understand the true LifeCycle of such a Context.**

#### Question 1:

What is the lifecycle diagram of a tenant specific WorkContext, Where should I store it, When it should be created/disposed ?

> NOTE: If the question 1 is provided, there is no need to answer the above one.

Suddenly I've found Orchard Project which seems to be a true masterpiece. Inside Orchard, the Context i'm talking about is called `WorkContext`.

I'm trying to understand the concept of WorkContext in Orchard Project. As far as I understand, here are some thoughts about WorkContext:

1. The WorkContext is a per-request lifetimeobject.
2. It is stored in `HttpContext.Items` (also there is a thread static implementation..).
3. It wraps the tenant IoC scope (ShellContext -> ShellContainer).
4. It is accessed through `IWorkContextAccessor`.

What I don't understand is:

#### Question 2:

Why do we need to include `IWorkContextAccessor` instance in route's DataTokens like this: `routeData.DataTokens["IWorkContextAccessor"] = _workContextAccessor;` ? Is this really necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of big question :-).

Firstly, `WorkContext` is more or less an abstraction of the HTTP context. A WorkContext lives as long as its work context scope lives (see `IWorkContextAccessor` that you can use to create work context scopes) so actually you can have multiple work contexts per request and you can have a work context independently of a request too (this happens in background tasks).

Such work contexts are thus externally managed contexts and thus somehow have to "travel" along with their scope until the latter is terminated: in Orchard the WC is either carried in the HTTP Context or in a thread static field (what is [not good enough and should be changed](https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20509)).

Thus basically a work context scope is the lowest dependency scope commonly used. It also has a parent, the shell's scope: this is the shell context (or more precisely, its lifetime scope). You can access a shell's (what is most of the time equal to a tenant) context through `IOrchardHost.GetShellContext()`. Work context scopes are actually created from the shell context's lifetime scope.

This also has a parent BTW that is the application-wide HostContainer.

Most of the time you don't have to manage the WC yourself since the ambient WC around requests and background tasks are managed for you.

Regarding your second question: I'm not entirely sure about this but AFAIK passing the WCA to the routeData just serves as a workaround to be able to access it (and thus, Orchard services) from strange places like HTML helpers and attributes that are not resolved through the DI container.

**Edit:** also added this to the Dojo Library, redacted and improved: http://orcharddojo.net/orchard-resources/Library/Wiki/WorkContext

Comment: Thank you so much for the anwser. `so actually you can have multiple work contexts per request` and `a workaround to be able to access it (and thus, Orchard services) from strange places like HTML helpers` made my day. Very good understanding.